# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart

**I try to send order with body content of List **
**but when I send that body I can't send for the flutter run was error with List is not type in String**
**I want to send the list of int to the server, not a string**

```
void _sendOrder(
  String Token,
  var name,
  var email,
  var phone,
  var phone2,
  var city,
  var area,
  List<int> idProduct,
  List<int> qtys,
  List<double> unti_price,
  var imageBase64) async {

var body = {
  'serial': '0',
  'customer_email': email,
  'customer_phone': phone,
  'customer_first_name': name,
  'customer_last_name': "UGOOD",
  'billing_first_name': name,
  'billing_last_name': "UGOOD" ,
  'billing_address_1': "Sudan",
  'billing_address_2': "Sudan",
  'billing_city': phone2,
  'billing_state': area ,
  'billing_zip': "0000",
  'billing_country': phone2,
  'shipping_first_name': name,
  'shipping_last_name': "UGOOD" ,
  'shipping_country': city,
  'shipping_address_1': "Sudan",
  'shipping_address_2': "Sudan",
  'shipping_city': city ,
  'shipping_state': area,
  'shipping_zip': "0000",
  'products[]' : idProduct,
  'qty[]' : qty,
  'unit_price[]' :unti_price,
  'prescription': imageBase64.toString(),
};
print([body]);
final String UrlProducts = "https://";
http.Response Response = await http.post(Uri.parse(UrlProducts),
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: Token},
    body:body);
if(Response.statusCode == 200){
  print(Response.body);
}else{
  print(Response.body);
}
```

**and this image from postman read server**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I contacted the developer of the back-end and he changed the receiver as receiving string and int**